# Why does uploading files from iOS devices doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari

I do have an upload form, where I upload my files to the server, which looks like this:

```html
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="file_upload"
              style="height: inherit; width: inherit; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
            <label>
                <div style="padding: 16px; text-align: center">
                    <input type="file" name="datei" accept="application/pdf" oninput="upload_file()">
                    <img src="res/icon/cloud_upload.svg"
                         style="width = 128px; height: 128px; display: inline-block;"><br>
                </div>
            </label>
        </form>
```

```js
    function upload_file() {
        let upload_form = document.getElementById('file_upload');
        upload_form.submit();
    }
```

Now I do have the problem that devices running iOS doesn't upload anything to the server. The problem does only occur on iOS (and iPadOS) and the issue is independent from the browser used.
Any suggestions on how to fix this issue on iOS?

Comment: Oh. We use php in this project so I added it here. But I realized there is no php in the question. edited the tags

Comment: How would you expect the user to select the file to be uploaded?

Comment: The image is clickable and then the filesystem opens and you can select a file. On PC and Android then the file is on the server. On iOS there is just no file uploaded (but the file dialog still opens)